# preg_match not working when wanting to detect multiple urls

Tags: php, url, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to automatically detect any link in a string and replace them with a `[index of link]`. For example if i have a string like `test https://www.google.com/ mmh http://stackoverflow.com/` the result will be `test [0] mmh [1]`.

Right now i tried with this

```
$reg_exUrl = '/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i';
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $_POST['commento'], $url)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($url); $i++) { 
        $_POST['commento'] = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "[" . $i . "]", $_POST['commento']);
    }
}
```

but i keep getting `test [0] mmh [0]`, if i try a `var_dump(count($url))` i always get 1 as a result. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, an even better solution here would be to split the incoming string into an array of strings between each `url` segment and then insert `[$i]` between consecutive non-url components.

```
# better solution, perform a split.
function process_line2($input) {
    $regex_url = '/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i';
    # split the incoming string into an array of non-url segments
    # preg_split does not trim leading or trailing empty segments
    $non_url_segments = preg_split($regex_url, $input, -1);

    # inside the array, combine each successive non-url segment
    # with the next index
    $out = [];
    $count = count($non_url_segments);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        # add the segment
        array_push($out, $non_url_segments[$i]);
        # add its index surrounded by brackets on all segments but the last one
        if ($i < $count -1) {
            array_push($out, '[' . $i . ']');
        }
    }
    # join strings with no whitespace
    return implode('', $out);
}
```

`preg_match` only returns the first result, so it doesn't give you the number of urls matching your regular expression. You need to extract the first element of the array returned by `preg_match_all`.

The second error is that you are not using the `limit` argument of `preg_replace`, so all of your urls are getting replaced at the same time.

From the documentation for `preg_replace`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

The parameters are

> mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )

in particular the limit parameter defaults to `-1` (no limit)

> limit: The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1 (no limit).

You need to set an explicit limit of 1.

Elaborating a bit on replacing `preg_match` with `preg_match_all`, you need  to extract the [0] component from it since `preg_match_all` returns an array of arrays. For example:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "https://www.google.com/"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "http://stackoverflow.com/"
  }
}
```

Here is an example with the fixes incorporated.

```
<?php 

# original function
function process_line($input) {

    $reg_exUrl = '/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i';
    if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $input, $url)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($url); $i++) { 
            $input = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "[" . $i . "]", $input);
        }
    }

    return $input;

}

# function with fixes incorporated
function process_line1($input) {

    $reg_exUrl = '/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i';
    if(preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $input, $url)) {
        $url_matches = $url[0];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($url_matches); $i++) { 
            echo $i;
            # add explicit limit of 1 to arguments of preg_replace
            $input = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "[" . $i . "]", $input, 1);
        }
    }

    return $input;

}

$input = "test https://www.google.com/ mmh http://stackoverflow.com/";

$input = process_line1($input);

echo $input;

?>
```